# Why can a SharePoint user read and modify OneNote Documents online, but not on his local OneNote?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, onenote

We're using OneNote in our company and have a bunch of OneNote Documents which are saved in our SharePoint like this:

`https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/intranet/groups/softwaredevelopment/_layouts/15/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=ExampleOneNoteDocument`

as you can see in the link, this specific OneNote Document was saved under "softwaredevelopment" - only members of the softwaredevelopment group have access to this folder.

Now I have a co-worker which isn't in the softwaredevelopment department but still needs access to this OneNote Document. So I share the OneNote Document with the co-worker and he gets an e-mail with a link he can use to open the document.

Now OneNoteOnline opens the document and it can be read and modified online by this user. If I want to open this document in the users OneNote Desktop App, it says he doesn't have permission to do this. The following is the error screenshot (unfortunately in german):

[image]

Notes:

- I'm not the owner of this document, but I have permission to share it with my co-worker
- It also didn't work when I added the co-worker to the softwaredevelopment group
- the user uses the same account to login to sharepoint, onenote, office etc.

Questions:

- Why is it possible to read and modify the document in OneNote Online but not in the Desktop app?
- Which permissions are used to grant access to the Documents? Is it sharepoint itself (like admins have access to everything, normal users not), or should it actually be a group permission like I described but didn't work?
- How do I get this Document into my co-workers OneNote Desktop App?

I'm not really a SharePoint Pro, so if I should tackle this whole thing in another way (like save the documents somewhere else) feel free to advise me to do it ;-).

Edit: Just so you know, this error doesn't occur only for one user or for one document, we have plenty of documents and users which can be edited online, but not in the desktop app

Comment: Does this only happen in OneNote or also in Word or Excel?

Comment: @MHeld I just tried it, uploaded an excel file and was able to open from my co-workers computer in excel online, when I clicked "edit document in excel desktop app" it opened the file in the desktop app, but it was write protected (not sure if this is expected or not)

Comment: Does this happen if your co-worker explicitly signs out of any and all accounts via OneNote (File | Account | Sign out) and then signs back in with the same account used to access the SharePoint site? It may be a stretch, but I'd also try clearing all Internet Explorer cookies. I'd also double-check the Windows credential manager.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it is the same account? The windows credentials sometimes might have the same email account but that doesn't mean it's the same account or that you use the same password, there is the company account and then the microsoft account.

Answer (score 0):

Does your co-worker use the same account for the Office on his local machine as he uses for logging in to SharePoint?
It may be possible that his local OneNote is trying to open the file with a different account, therefore he gets the error.

Comment: yes it's the exact same account

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it possible to read and modify the document in OneNote Online
>   but not in the Desktop app?

**Issues mostly coupled with permission. Or in some instances document may be checked-out by other person. Cant say blindy without dig deep and hope you use same method to open it as below!!** 
[image: Open One note with client]

> Which permissions are used to grant access to the Documents? Is it
>   sharepoint itself (like admins have access to everything, normal users
>   not), or should it actually be a group permission like I described but
>   didn't work?

**Design permission is must**

> How do I get this Document into my co-workers OneNote Desktop App?

**You should share the whole NoteBook as below or may be share on SharePoint library** 
[image: Share NoteBook]